# Joining a list of numbers in a .txt file with ,[space]

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd

Hi I managed to get the code below to create a list of numbers and place a comma at the end of each number created However, it has proven to be quite the challenge to get them on the same line separated by a `,[space]`

```
@ECHO OFF
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
set _Output=%UserProfile%\Desktop\NumGen.txt

::only change these three lines
set "start=1"  ::starts from this number
set "amount=10" ::amount of files created
set "length=5" ::length of fileNames
set "join_with=, " ::what to join each number with

set /a "last=%start%+%amount%"
for /l %%i in (%start%,1,%last%) do (
set "folderName=0000000000%%i"
set "folderName=!folderName:~-%length%!%join_with%"
>>"%_Output%" ECHO.!folderName!
)
pause
```

so my output at the moment is

```
00001, 
00002, 
00003, 
00004, 
00005, 
00006, 
00007, 
00008, 
00009, 
00010, 
00011,
```

However I would like it to be

```
00001, 00002, 00003, 00004, 00005, 00006, 00007, 00008, 00009, 00010, 00011
```

I have windows 10 64bit. Any help will be appreciated

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After a long break I decided to give this another bash and presto. Success :-)

```
::CallScript
@ECHO OFF
CALL :ScriptA
CALL :ScriptB
CALL :ScriptC
pause
goto :eof


:ScriptA
@ECHO OFF
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
set _Output=%UserProfile%\Desktop\NumGen.txt
::only change these three lines
set "start=1"  
set "amount=10" 
set "length=5" 
set "join_with=, " 
set /a "last=%start%+%amount%"
for /l %%i in (%start%,1,%last%) do (
set "folderName=0000000000%%i"
set "folderName=!folderName:~-%length%!%join_with%"
>>"%_Output%" ECHO.!folderName!
)
goto :eof


:ScriptB
@ECHO OFF
    setlocal enableextensions enabledelayedexpansion
set "var="
for /f "usebackq delims=" %%a in ("%UserProfile%\Desktop\NumGen.txt") do set "var=!var!%%a" 
echo %var%> "%UserProfile%\Desktop\NumList.txt"
goto :eof


:ScriptC
@ECHO OFF
del "%UserProfile%\Desktop\NumGen.txt"
goto :eof
```

This code determines the starting number, the amount of numbers, the length of the numbers and joins them with `, "`

Then `ScriptB` concatenates each number together with the `, "` and saves to `NumList.txt`

Lastly the script deletes the `NumGen.txt` file.

Answer (score 3):

`echo` is not able to do that. But there is a workaround, (ab)using the `set` command:

```
for /l %%i in (1,1,5) do (
  <nul set /p "=%%i, "
)
echo(
```

Comment: Thanks Stephan I'm just having a bit of a problem applying this (ab)using work around XD. Could you add an full script example if it's not too much trouble

Comment: just think of `<nul set /p "=somestring"` as something like `echo /nolinefeed somestring` (of course `/nolinefeed` doesn't work with `echo`)

Answer (score 1):

Stephan has one solution with SET /P. The other option is to build the entire string within an environment variable, and then write after the loop ends. This is significantly faster, but it will fail if the final string length exceeds ~8191 bytes.

```
set "str="
for /l %%i in (%start%,1,%last%) do (
  set "folderName=0000000000%%i"
  set "str=!str!!folderName:~-%length%!%join_with%"
)
>>"%_Output%" ECHO.!str!
```

You could remove the unwanted trailing `,` if you want:

```
>>"%_Output%" ECHO.!str:~0,-2!
```